# how to find a path visit as much as possible vertices?

Tags: c++, graph, graph-algorithm

Given a square grid (undirected graph), is there any way to find a path which will visit as much as possible vertices.

each vertex can be visit only once. It means that the path will be Hamilton tour if exist, or be a longest path.

The graph has some walls. Wall is a vertex has no edge connect to neighbors.

I has a solution (in mind), but it's very similar to find all path and chose the first one has most vertices visited.

> 1. Find a path will visit all neighbors from given start vertex to the end (no way can go).
> 2. look back to the current path until the starting vertex, if there is any vertex has neighbors outside of the current path, process like
>      step 1 from the found vertex and its new neighbors.
> 3. analysis and choose the longest path (has most vertices).

I found [similar problem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/14390/find-a-simple-path-visiting-all-marked-vertices), cannot understand what does @Juho mean:

> Choose a successor si to top(S), and try to find a path si−1⇝si avoiding vertices in F. If a path is found, insert the vertices on the path si−1⇝si to F.

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment there.

my solution get performance trouble, I guess. Any suggestion?

Comment: I would try a [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).

Comment: could you explain more ?

Comment: What part of the article was unclear? Do a depth-first search, avoiding self-intersection, and whenever you reach a dead end, note the length of the path (i.e. the number of nodes visited). If the path is the longest yet discovered, record it.

Comment: hmm, DFS still can not resolve my problem. Is there any condition between V,E to show that graph does not have Hamilton tour?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Hamiltonian Path problem. It's NP-complete so you'll need to do an exhaustive search. Get your brute-force on. I can only suggest that it is possible to use threading to alleviate your performance problem; divide up your starting vertices evenly amongst your available threads. Terminate in the event that you find a Hamiltonian Path, else the longest path wins.

The algorithm itself is just going to have to find all possible paths. I there is possibly a heuristic to stop bothering with a path that seems to be getting bad results but that will mean the solution may not always be correct.